# Script echo current command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Suppose I'm running a PowerShell script that takes several input parameters. The command looks like:

```
psScript.ps1 -arg1 "arg1value" -arg2 "arg2value"
```

Is there a way to store this exact command in a variable within the script so that I can log it?

Specifically, I'd like to know what to assign to the variable $currentCommand:

```
$currentCommand = <something>
Write-Host "currently running script " $currentCommand
```

Such that the Write-Host output would be the exact command line used to invoke the script. If the script command was the same as above, for example, then the output would be:

> currently running script psScript.ps1 -arg1 "arg1value" -arg2
>   "arg2value"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may suit your needs:

```
Write-Host "currently running script " $myinvocation.Line
```

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/05/31/getting-all-your-parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The $MyInvocation variable will have the information. Here is a good [blog post](http://poshoholic.com/2008/03/18/powershell-deep-dive-using-myinvocation-and-invoke-expression-to-support-dot-sourcing-and-direct-invocation-in-shared-powershell-scripts/) about it.